# Count the occurrences of items in ArrayList and list top N items

Tags: java, sorting, guava

### Scenario:

As a follow-up of this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293900/modelling-a-parcel-management-application), I have a `java.util.ArrayList<Parcel>` and a `Parcel` object.

```
public class Parcel {
    /** The name. */
    private String name;

    /** The address. */
    private String address;

    /** The contact no. */
    private String contactNo;

    /** The postal code. */
    private String postalCode;

    // Accessors and mutators
}
```

And I have a method which returns list of parcels from an `InputStream`.

```
List<Parcel> parcels = parcelManager.getParcelList(inputStream);


@Test
public void testParcelBeanReturnCount() {
   Assert.assertEquals(13, tester.getParcelList(inputStream)); // works fine.
}
```

Now, how do I list the top N postal codes along with the number of parcels delivered(to a particular postal code)? I tried with `Multiset` API from Guava.

```
Multiset<Parcel> postalCodeCount = HashMultiset.create(parcels);

System.out.println(postalCodeCount.size()); // 13.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Parcel` needs well defined `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

See [HashCode and Equals method in Java object](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html)

Alternatively, You could use Java8:

```
List l = parcels.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getPostalCode()))
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e2.getValue().size(), e1.getValue().size()))
         .limit(N) //Top N
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```